# Python date comparison not working in .exe app

Tags: pandas, numpy, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I have created a python script that works fine when running it in Spyder.  I then freeze it with pyinstaller.  When I run the .exe app, I get the following error.

[image]

Here is the relevent code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from datetime import datetime, time
import teradata as td
import numpy as np
import smtplib
import xlrd #needed for .exe

### Import Fleet Plan file ###
path = '\\\PHX43XCIFSC0001\Planning'
folder = '\Aircraft Availability'
file = '\\NP Fleet Plan.xlsx'
sheet = 'Mainline'
colnames = [0,2]
link = path + folder + file
update = pd.Timestamp.date(pd.Timestamp(datetime.fromtimestamp(
        os.path.getmtime(link)), unit='s'))
mydata = pd.read_excel(link, sheet_name = sheet, header=colnames, index=None)
df = mydata

# Flatten multiindex to single columns
df.columns = (['{}:{}'.format(i[0], i[1]) for i in df])
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'mDate', df.columns[1]:'DOW'})

# Remove blank columns and Fleet level columns
xcolunassigned = [col for col in df.columns if 'Unnamed'  in col]
df = df.drop(xcolunassigned, axis=1)
xcolfleet = [col for col in df.columns if 'FLEET'  in col]
df = df.drop(xcolfleet, axis=1)

# Transpose data in to vectors
dft = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['mDate', 'DOW'], var_name='Status', value_name='mCount')

# Split Subfleets, join Legacy, remove 0 and NaN
dft[['Status', 'SubFleet']] = dft.Status.str.split(':',expand=True)
sDate = min(dft.mDate)
dft = dft.dropna()
dft = dft.reset_index(drop=True)
dft = dft[dft['mCount'] != 0]
dft = dft.reset_index(drop=True)

# Delete all data prior to today
dft = dft[dft['mDate'] >= datetime.combine(datetime.today(), time.min) ]
dft = dft.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I am wondering if there is a dependency that I need to explicitly import like I had to for the xlrd library.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: `dft[dft['mDate'] >= datetime.today()]` ? @Michael

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but it did not change anything.  I believe the problem is when running the .exe, the mDate is not coming across as a date.  But, since it is a date when running the script, I can't change it to a date, at least I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Comment: Update:  The issue is further up in the code.  For some reason when I run the code with .exe, my data is imported with an index column even though I explicitly told it not to.  Not sure why it did this, but I am now just retooling to remove this extra column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There ended up being an issue with the .exe not loading some of the dependencies for the libraries I needed.  After explicitly calling the dependencies in my code, the .exe application worked perfectly.